# web3js send transaction failed when contract modify mapping data , but remix work

Tags: mapping, solidity, web3js, contract, remix

first, web3 version: `1.0.0-beta.36`

the contract code is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract Main {
  struct Model {
    uint256 key;
    uint64 createTime;
  }

  Model[] public models;

  mapping(uint256 => address) public modelOwner;

  function total() view public returns (uint256) {
    return models.length;
  }

  function getData(uint256 _tokenId) view returns ( uint256, uint64){

    Model _model = models[_tokenId];
    return  (_model.key, _model.createTime);
  }

  function createData(uint256 _key, address _owner) returns (uint){

    Model memory _model = Model({key : _key, createTime : uint64(now)});

    uint256 newModelId = models.push(_model) - 1;

    // modelOwner[newModelId] = _owner;

    return newModelId;
  }
}
```

I send transaction by remix and web3.js:

```
myContract.methods.createData(
 key,
 addressA
).send({
 from: addressB 
})
```

the problem is :

1. when I remove the code `modelOwner[newModelId] = _owner;` in function `createData`, web3 and remix both work **(List models increase)**;
2. when I add `modelOwner[newModelId] = _owner;`, remix work, but web3 failed, because the result of the method `getData` returned is not correct **(List models not increase)**;

Comment: With just the information you provide it will be hard to help you. Explain what you get from `getData`, in each case and what you would expect to get. Also when you say that the transaction from `web3` fails what exactly do you mean? Does it revert? If it reverts only from `web3` and not from `remix` then you probably do something wrong when sending the transaction from `web3`, since the contract executes in the same way no matter where the transaction comes from.

Comment: If removing that line makes a difference, my guess is you're just running out of gas. Try `.send({ from: addressB, gas: '1000000' })` to make sure you're supplying enough gas.

Comment: @smarx oh, I forgot it... it works for web3js transaction.

Comment: Your question says "remix work, but web3 failed", but now you're saying "it works for web3js transaction". Does that mean you no longer have a question?

Comment: @smarx yes, I add 'gas' in transaction, and it works